# Authenticate earthengine CLI using a service account?

Tags: google-earth-engine, authentication, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to upload a CSV to Google Earth Engine as an asset through a Python script. Turns out the only way to do this other than using the GUI (which I need to avoid using) is to use the `earthengine` CLI. I use the `subprocess` module to run `earthengine upload` in my Python script. The problem I am having is that in the future, I cannot authenticate Google Earth Engine through the use of `earthengine authenticate` and need to use a Google Cloud service account to accomplish this. I've been using these lines of code in my script:

```
service_account = "earthengineapi@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
credentials = ee.ServiceAccountCredentials(service_account, "private-key.json")
ee.Initialize(credentials)
```

but this only authenticates Earth Engine Python and does not authenticate the `earthengine` CLI.

Is there a way I can use a service account to authenticate my Earth Engine account so that I can use the `earthengine upload` command in my Python script?

Again, I need to avoid authenticating the CLI with `earthengine authenticate`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue until my colleagues stumbled across two options this week:

1. Specify the `--service_account_file` option to your `earthengine` CLI commands, e.g. `earthengine --service_account_file ee-sa-file.json upload ...`
2. Authenticate in your Python script as you've already been doing with `ee.Initialize`, and use `ee.data.startTableIngestion` to upload from your script - see
   https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-data-starttableingestion